# Multiple project on apache2

Tags: apache

I have my apache which is correctly setup and I would like to add multiple project :

```
/var/www/html/project1
/var/www/html/project2
```

this is working well with aliases like this : 
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Alias /project1 /var/www/html/project1/public
        Alias /project2 /var/www/html/project2/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/project1/public>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/project2/public>
          AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

And I can access them by :

```
myip/project1
myip/project2
```

But I would like to have my project 1 only accessed by the root like this :

```
myip/
```

And the project 2 still remains like it is.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentRoot should be /var/www/html/project1/public